# Outlook performing an AutoCorrect that isn't defined in settings or dictionary

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, autocorrect

When composing an email today, I typed the word "autodiscover" and Outlook AutoCorrected it to "Autodiscover". I was surprised at this and so I looked in the AutoCorrect Options, only to discover that there is no entry for "autodiscover" in the list:
[image]
I saw that "Automatically use suggestions from the spelling checker" was enabled, so I also took a look in the Custom Dictionaries word list, but there's no occurrence of "Autodiscover" in there, either.

Where is this particular AutoCorrect coming from?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce in my Outlook or Word even when "autodiscover" is not the first word in a sentence. It also occurs to other particular nouns like "america","england",etc. This might because these words have been added to the spelling dictionary and the autocorrect feature is correcting the capitalization on them automatically.

To work around the issue, you can clear the checkbox of Automatically Use Suggestions from the Spelling Checker:

[image]

Or you can add "autodiscover" as an exception if you don't want to change the auto capitalization of other nouns:

[image]